# System.Exception when running MonoMac Samples that use OpenGL

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

This is my first post to stackOverflow so I hope you are kind to me :). After setting up my system with XCode v4.4, MonoDevelop v3.0.5 and the latest development branch from MonoMac (v2.10.9) git hub I keep getting these exceptions when running the MonoMac samples that include OpenGL any other samples work as expected. Here is a stack trace of the exception:-

```
2012-08-27 15:23:17.117 NeHeLesson1[229:1207] invalid pixel format
2012-08-27 15:23:17.119 NeHeLesson1[229:1207] invalid context

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Invalid parameters to context creation
at MonoMac.OpenGL.CGLContext..ctor (intptr) <0x0006f>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenGLContext.get_CGLContext () <0x00053>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView.SetupDisplayLink () <0x00089>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView..ctor (System.Drawing.RectangleF,MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenGLContext) <0x00283>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView..ctor (System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x00033>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ee521f2b-bbc7-4e1d-ad69-1022ce59ef12 (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x00077>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.ee521f2b-bbc7-4e1d-ad69-1022ce59ef12 (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x0008f>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr) <0x00003>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowController.get_Window () <0x0007b>
at NeHeLesson1.MainWindowController.get_Window () <0x00013>
at NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x0003b>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.[NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x00033>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.[NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x000fb>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[]) <0x00003>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
at NeHeLesson1.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x00017>

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: Invalid parameters to context creation
at MonoMac.OpenGL.CGLContext..ctor (intptr) <0x0006f>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenGLContext.get_CGLContext () <0x00053>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView.SetupDisplayLink () <0x00089>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView..ctor (System.Drawing.RectangleF,MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenGLContext) <0x00283>
at NeHeLesson1.MyOpenGLView..ctor (System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x00033>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ee521f2b-bbc7-4e1d-ad69-1022ce59ef12 (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x00077>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.ee521f2b-bbc7-4e1d-ad69-1022ce59ef12 (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,System.Drawing.RectangleF) <0x0008f>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr) <0x00003>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowController.get_Window () <0x0007b>
at NeHeLesson1.MainWindowController.get_Window () <0x00013>
at NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x0003b>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.[NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x00033>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.[NeHeLesson1.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) <0x000fb>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[]) <0x00003>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
at NeHeLesson1.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
```

The code that is causing the error is:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoMac.Foundation;
using MonoMac.AppKit;
using MonoMac.CoreVideo;
using MonoMac.CoreGraphics;
using MonoMac.OpenGL;

namespace NeHeLesson1
{
    public partial class MyOpenGLView : MonoMac.AppKit.NSView
    {

        NSOpenGLContext openGLContext;
        NSOpenGLPixelFormat pixelFormat;

        MainWindowController controller;

        CVDisplayLink displayLink;

        NSObject notificationProxy;

        [Export("initWithFrame:")]
        public MyOpenGLView (RectangleF frame) : this(frame, null)
        {
        }

        public MyOpenGLView (RectangleF frame, NSOpenGLContext context) : base(frame)
        {
            var attribs = new object [] {
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.Accelerated,
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.NoRecovery,
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.DoubleBuffer,
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.ColorSize, 24,
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.DepthSize, 16 };

            pixelFormat = new NSOpenGLPixelFormat (attribs);

            if (pixelFormat == null)
                Console.WriteLine ("No OpenGL pixel format");

            // NSOpenGLView does not handle context sharing, so we draw to a custom NSView instead
            openGLContext = new NSOpenGLContext (pixelFormat, context);

            openGLContext.MakeCurrentContext ();

            // Synchronize buffer swaps with vertical refresh rate
            openGLContext.SwapInterval = true;

            // Initialize our newly created view.
            InitGL ();

            SetupDisplayLink();

            // Look for changes in view size
            // Note, -reshape will not be called automatically on size changes because NSView does not export it to override 
            notificationProxy = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (NSView.NSViewGlobalFrameDidChangeNotification, HandleReshape);
        }

        public override void DrawRect (RectangleF dirtyRect)
        {
            // Ignore if the display link is still running
            if (!displayLink.IsRunning && controller != null)
                DrawView ();
        }

        public override bool AcceptsFirstResponder ()
        {
            // We want this view to be able to receive key events
            return true;
        }

        public override void LockFocus ()
        {
            base.LockFocus ();
            if (openGLContext.View != this)
                openGLContext.View = this;
        }

        public override void KeyDown (NSEvent theEvent)
        {
            controller.KeyDown (theEvent);
        }

        public override void MouseDown (NSEvent theEvent)
        {
            controller.MouseDown (theEvent);
        }

        // All Setup For OpenGL Goes Here
        public bool InitGL ()
        {
                // Enables Smooth Shading  
                GL.ShadeModel (ShadingModel.Smooth);
                // Set background color to black     
                GL.ClearColor (Color.Black);

                // Setup Depth Testing

                // Depth Buffer setup
                GL.ClearDepth (1.0);
                // Enables Depth testing
                GL.Enable (EnableCap.DepthTest);
                // The type of depth testing to do
                GL.DepthFunc (DepthFunction.Lequal);

                // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
                GL.Hint (HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

                return true;
        }

        private void DrawView ()
        {
            // This method will be called on both the main thread (through -drawRect:) and a secondary thread (through the display link rendering loop)
            // Also, when resizing the view, -reshape is called on the main thread, but we may be drawing on a secondary thread
            // Add a mutex around to avoid the threads accessing the context simultaneously 
            openGLContext.CGLContext.Lock ();

            // Make sure we draw to the right context
            openGLContext.MakeCurrentContext ();

            // Delegate to the scene object for rendering
            controller.Scene.DrawGLScene ();

            openGLContext.FlushBuffer ();

            openGLContext.CGLContext.Unlock ();
        }


        private void SetupDisplayLink ()
        {
            // Create a display link capable of being used with all active displays
            displayLink = new CVDisplayLink ();

            // Set the renderer output callback function
            displayLink.SetOutputCallback (MyDisplayLinkOutputCallback);

            // Set the display link for the current renderer
            CGLContext cglContext = openGLContext.CGLContext;
            CGLPixelFormat cglPixelFormat = PixelFormat.CGLPixelFormat;
            displayLink.SetCurrentDisplay (cglContext, cglPixelFormat);

        }

        public CVReturn MyDisplayLinkOutputCallback (CVDisplayLink displayLink, ref CVTimeStamp inNow, ref CVTimeStamp inOutputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, ref CVOptionFlags flagsOut)
        {
            CVReturn result = GetFrameForTime (inOutputTime);

            return result;
        }


        private CVReturn GetFrameForTime (CVTimeStamp outputTime)
        {
            // There is no autorelease pool when this method is called because it will be called from a background thread
            // It's important to create one or you will leak objects
            using (NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {

                // Update the animation
                DrawView ();
            }

            return CVReturn.Success;

        }

        public NSOpenGLContext OpenGLContext {
            get { return openGLContext; }
        }

        public NSOpenGLPixelFormat PixelFormat {
            get { return pixelFormat; }
        }

        public MainWindowController MainController {
            set { controller = value; }
        }

        public void UpdateView ()
        {
            // This method will be called on the main thread when resizing, but we may be drawing on a secondary thread through the display link
            // Add a mutex around to avoid the threads accessing the context simultaneously
            openGLContext.CGLContext.Lock ();

            // Delegate to the scene object to update for a change in the view size
            controller.Scene.ResizeGLScene (Bounds);
            openGLContext.Update ();

            openGLContext.CGLContext.Unlock ();
        }

        private void HandleReshape (NSNotification note)
        {
            UpdateView ();
        }

        public void StartAnimation ()
        {
            if (displayLink != null && !displayLink.IsRunning)
                displayLink.Start ();
        }

        public void StopAnimation ()
        {
            if (displayLink != null && displayLink.IsRunning)
                displayLink.Stop ();
        }

        // Clean up the notifications
        public void DeAllocate()
        {
            displayLink.Stop();
            displayLink.SetOutputCallback(null);

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(notificationProxy); 
        }

        [Export("toggleFullScreen:")]
        public void toggleFullScreen (NSObject sender)
        {
                controller.toggleFullScreen (sender);
        }       
    }
}
```

scene.cs

```
namespace NeHeLesson1
{
    public class Scene : NSObject
    {
        public Scene () : base()
        {
        }

        // Resize And Initialize The GL Window 
        //      - See also the method in the MyOpenGLView Constructor about the NSView.NSViewGlobalFrameDidChangeNotification
        public void ResizeGLScene (RectangleF bounds)
        {
            // Reset The Current Viewport
            GL.Viewport (0, 0, (int)bounds.Size.Width, (int)bounds.Size.Height);
            // Select The Projection Matrix
            GL.MatrixMode (MatrixMode.Projection);
            // Reset The Projection Matrix
            GL.LoadIdentity ();

            // Set perspective here - Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
            Perspective (45, bounds.Size.Width / bounds.Size.Height, 0.1, 100);

            // Select The Modelview Matrix
            GL.MatrixMode (MatrixMode.Modelview);
            // Reset The Modelview Matrix
            GL.LoadIdentity ();
        }

        // This creates a symmetric frustum.
        // It converts to 6 params (l, r, b, t, n, f) for glFrustum()
        // from given 4 params (fovy, aspect, near, far)
        public static void Perspective (double fovY, double aspectRatio, double front, double back)
        {
            const double DEG2RAD = Math.PI / 180;

            // tangent of half fovY
            double tangent = Math.Tan (fovY / 2 * DEG2RAD);

            // half height of near plane
            double height = front * tangent;

            // half width of near plane
            double width = height * aspectRatio;

            // params: left, right, bottom, top, near, far
            GL.Frustum (-width, width, -height, height, front, back);
        }

        // This method renders our scene and where all of your drawing code will go.
        // The main thing to note is that we've factored the drawing code out of the NSView subclass so that
        // the full-screen and non-fullscreen views share the same states for rendering 
        public bool DrawGLScene ()
        {
            // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
            GL.Clear (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
            GL.LoadIdentity ();

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this issue as its stopping from running MonoMac and MonoGameFrameWork, am i missing something from my setup. BTW I was able to run all OpenGLExtentions Viewer tests so I openGL seems to work.

Jase

Comment: You should post your actual code

Comment: Well the code is just the NeHeLesson1 from the MonoGameFrameWork samples, But I will try post all the code up soon.

Answer (score -1):

Things I would do would be...

1. Go to http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html
2. Download Mono 2.10.9 SDK
3. Make sure you have installed X11 - http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/22/how-to-install-x11-in-os-x/
4. If you want to use MonoGame and then do a "git clone git@github.com:mono/MonoGame.git" followed by "cd MonoGame" then the command "git submodule update --init --recursive", so that the Samples and StarterKit submodules are downloaded.

Note : NeheLesson1, as per above, is not a MonoGame Framework Sample. It is a pure OpenGL sample. MonoGame Framework samples can be found Samples and StarterKit subdirectories of the MonoGame repo you would have cloned above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, not tried these steps yet but can you breifly explain why I need to install X11? by the way I am on v10.7.4 of MacOS. The reason I included the NeHeLession1 is that this demostrates the exception without the MonoGameSample framework which I assume wraps code like this. I can actually get this example to run by commenting out the "NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.Accelerated,". Is there anyway to switch of hardware acceleration in the MonoGameFramework?

Comment: As per the MonoMac download link "System.Windows.Forms applications require X11." I've had a quick search of the MonoGame code base of the Mac port, & I don't see any calls to NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute.Accelerated. This may be happening inside OpenTK & MonoGame may not try to override it. So is the problem that your machine does not support hardware acceleration? Could it be running on a VM? I'm asking because I'm using a Mac Book Pro & have the MonoGame samples & starter kits running just fine. Seems odd to want to turn off HW acceleration these days when you get it for free with most HW.

Comment: I am running on a VM, do the MonoGame samples not work on a VM? LIke I said before I have got the iOS MonoGame samples to work so I think I should be able to convert my XNA game to using the frame work?

Comment: I've not tested under a VM, only real hardware. Does your VM support 100% of what Mac hardware does. If it  does, it should work. Yes the idea is that if iOS samples work, then the same samples for MacOS should also work.